# Rodar trechos de código em paralelo

Tags: java, thread, concorrência

Olá, eu queria saber como executar uma thread em seguida da outra por um determinado tempo, por exemplo:

```
Thread x = new Thread(() -> {
// qualquer código, pode ter até um while(true)...
});
Thread x2 = new Thread(() -> {
// qualquer código, pode ter até um while(true)...
});
```

Tenho uma thread x que deverá rodar por 3s, após esse tempo ela deverá pausar e em seguida a x2 deverá iniciar, mas não pode conter nenhum código adicional dentro do runnable dela.
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você quer usar threads para tarefas síncronas? Por quê?

Comment: Porque eu tenho que executar vários códigos independentes em um determinado período de tempo, tipo quero x segundos para executar um trecho de código, mas que dê para voltar onde ele parou. Não sei se deixei claro :/

Comment: @V.Azzone Não consegui entender muito bem. Sugiro que edite sua pergunta e forneça mais detalhes do que está querendo fazer.

Answer (score -1):

Caro colega,

O melhor nesse caso é criar uma uma classe que herda Thread e inplementar o método run(){}. Esse método você pode colocar um synchronized no método, dessa forma, quando você pode chamar o método start e para pausar só chamar o método sleep(tempo), passando no parametro o tempo que você precisa que ele aguarde.